# ArcPy: How best to handle output that could be a shapefile or feature class?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, feature-class

In many Esri examples, including this [one](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm), they code in the output ".shp".  What is the best way if you want to be able to handle a shapefile OR a feature class output.  Let say if a GDB is provided as the workspace, then features class, if a folder directory then .shp.  Is there any ArcPy built-in to handing this?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you just supply the path to the output featureclass which can be a shapefile featureclass, a file geodatabase featureclass, an enterprise geodatabase featureclass, etc...

Comment: The parent folder just has to be the geodatabase (`.sde` or `.gdb`) or a feature dataset in a geodatabase, and the feature class name must not have a `.shp` suffix.

Comment: For example this ouput will create a shape: `r"C:\GIS\data\outputdataset"` and this a feature class in a database `r"C:\GIS\data\database.gdb\outputdataset"`. Just leave out the `.shp`, arcpy will add it if output is a folder

Comment: Good answers thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, it doesnt matter. Just supply the path and ~filename without the `.shp` extension and arcpy will know what to do.

For example:

- With a folder named data `r"C:\GIS\data\outputdataset"` a shape named `outputdataset.shp` (and all other shape extensions) will be created in it
- If the output is a database, like a file geodatabase arcpy will create a feature class in it, example: `r"C:\GIS\data\database.gdb\outputdataset"`